# Put image next to h1

Tags: html, css

How do I put the image next to the h1 text? The image on the left and the text on the right. Thanks in advance!

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

h1 {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<header class="head">
  <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_jpg,q_auto:eco/61b4738b-e1e1-4786-8f6c-26aa0008e80b/swoosh-logo-black.png" class="pic">
  <h1 class="home" id="home">Hi</h1>
```

Comment: try by creating a new css rule

.head {
    display: flex;
}

This apply flexbox layout to the header, thus making the elements to stay side-by-side.

Comment: Check out [flexbox in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the text is so long it would come below the image. Do you want it to flow under the image or do you want it to stay in its own right-hand 'column'?

Answer (score 1):

It may be most efficient to use flexbox to resolve this layout issue. Adding
*display: flex;* to the parent element will create the row layout you're looking for and some additional CSS properties will center the children elements if desired. Check out the complete guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to really control the position of every element if needed.

```css
.head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="head">
  <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_jpg,q_auto:eco/61b4738b-e1e1-4786-8f6c-26aa0008e80b/swoosh-logo-black.png" class="pic">
  <h1 class="home" id="home">Hi</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add `float: right` to `h1`:

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

h1 {
  float: right;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<header class="head">
  <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_jpg,q_auto:eco/61b4738b-e1e1-4786-8f6c-26aa0008e80b/swoosh-logo-black.png" class="pic">
  <h1 class="home" id="home">Hi</h1>
```

Or `display: inline-block` to `h1`:

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<header class="head">
  <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_jpg,q_auto:eco/61b4738b-e1e1-4786-8f6c-26aa0008e80b/swoosh-logo-black.png" class="pic">
  <h1 class="home" id="home">Hi</h1>
```

Keep in mind that the image has a fixed width and the text has a relative width, so it will automatically flow over to the next line if the total width allowance is exceeded. To prevent this, simply set `width: fit content` on the `h1`.